# R: Sort links by distance to sectors in chord diagramm with circlize

Tags: r, chord-diagram, circlize

is it possible to sort the **links** in each sector of a **chord diagram** made with the **circlize** package **by distance** to the other sectors?

Normally, links could overlap near the tracks because of their position. This would be prohibited by changing it respectively.

[Example image with one link crossing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQgNL.png)

I have founded only the possibility to sort it by value size with `link.sort`, but this is not what I am looking for.

Thanks for the answer! Cheers.

Comment: question fits better [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: how about the `link.rank` argument?

Comment: @ZuguangGu No, as can be read [here](https://jokergoo.github.io/circlize_book/book/the-chorddiagram-function.html#orders-of-links) the `link.rank`argument only controlls the order of overlapping, not the ordering by the distance to other sectors.